# How to use cat and EOF in gnuplot to create a file while executing the gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a file, for.sh, in the gnuplot script during its execution.  The new file then will be called in the gnuplot script as

```
set xtics (`(sh for.sh)`)
```

The contents in for.sh should be these.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm Final-X-ticks.dat
KPATH=data1
TICK_position=data2
sed -n  '/crystal coordinates with respect/,/REPRODUCED(TRANSFORMED) DATASET/p' $KPATH | sed  '/crystal/d' | sed  '/REPRODUCED/d' | awk '{print $4}' | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' >  symbl.dat

line=$(cat symbl.dat | wc -l)
for i in `seq 1 1 $line`
do
echo " '{/Times-New  "  > symbl-$i.dat
cat symbl.dat |  tail -n $line | head -n "$i" | tail -n 1 >> symbl-$i.dat
echo " }'"  >> symbl-$i.dat
grep -i "coordinate" $TICK_position  | awk '{print $NF}' | head -n "$i" | tail -n 1 >>  kpoints-$i.dat
cat  kpoints-$i.dat | tail -n 1 | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }'  >> symbl-$i.dat
echo " ,"  >> symbl-$i.dat
cat symbl-$i.dat |  awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }' |  awk '{gsub(/Times-New[ \t]+(G|\$\\Gamma\$)/, "Symbol G")} 1' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }' >> Final-X-ticks.dat
done
rm  symbl-* symbl.dat  kpoints-*
```

I tried with

```
cat > for.sh <<EOF
above contents
EOF
```

but it gives me error

```
cat for.sh << EOF
^
"plot.gnu", line 19: invalid command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a datablock to hold the text, then print it out. For example,

```
$MYSCRIPT <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
rm Final-X-ticks.dat
...
rm  symbl-* symbl.dat  kpoints-*
EOF

set print "for.sh"
print $MYSCRIPT
set print

set xtics (`(bash ./for.sh)`)
```